# How to solve: the attachable property triggers was not found in style in a Grid Application

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro, datatrigger

I'm using Visual Studio 11 in Windows8. And setting the data trigger in a Grid Application (Metro) shows me this error in XAML:

> the attachable property triggers was not found in style

```
<Image Stretch="UniformToFill">
     <Image.Style>
         <Style TargetType="Image">
             <Setter Property="Source" Value="{Binding Image}"/>
             <Style.Triggers>
                 <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Image}" Value="{x:Null}">
                     <Setter Property="Source" Value="Images/Default.png"/>
                 </DataTrigger>
             </Style.Triggers>
         </Style>
    </Image.Style>
</Image>
```

Why show me this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Triggers [aren't supported](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-GB/winappswithcsharp/thread/77604041-b991-4f1e-9adb-78c701ac4d9a) in Windows 8 Metro style apps. I'd suggest you write a [converter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.data.ivalueconverter.aspx) which will replace null value with the default one.

Answer (score 3):

you can use VisualState instead of object.Triggers in Windows 8 Here is the code

```
 <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
<VisualStateGroup.Transitions>

  <!--Take one half second to transition to the PointerOver state.-->
  <VisualTransition To="PointerOver" 
                      GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.5"/>
</VisualStateGroup.Transitions>

<VisualState x:Name="Normal" />

<VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
<Storyboard> 
<ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBrush" 
Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color" To="Red" />
 </Storyboard> 
</VisualState> 
</VisualStateGroup>
</VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups> 
  <Grid.Background>
<SolidColorBrush x:Name="ButtonBrush" Color="Green"/>
 </Grid.Background>
</Grid>
 </ControlTemplate>
```